# Conditional volumes_from path

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm struggling with providing environment-specific configuration (say dev/qa/prod) to an application container. The closest I've got to my goal is this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: my-application:latest
    tty: true
    volumes_from:
      - configs:ro
  configs:
    image: my-configs:latest
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /configs/$ENV
```

If, say, we're deploying in the QA environment, the relevant configuration will be accessible at `/configs/qa` (from within the `app` service), meaning that in order to access these configs application will have to be aware of the environment it is running in, and I don't think it is something the application developers should be concerned about.

So my goal is to have `config`'s `/configs/$ENV` accessible as simply `/configs` from within the `app` service. How can I achieve that? My current idea is rebuilding `config`'s image:

```
FROM my-configs:latest
ARG env
RUN cp -rf /configs/$env /tmp/configs && rm -rf /configs && cp -rf /tmp/configs /configs
ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh
```

Then updated `docker-compose.yml` will look like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: my-application:latest
    tty: true
    volumes_from:
      - configs:ro
  configs:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        env: $ENV
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /configs
```

Are there any better options or should I go through with my idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use environment variables in the `volumes:` specification

```
volumes:
  - /config/$ENV:/config
```

I'd put this in the service definition that's actually using it.  You don't need to put this into its own image.  I'd also tend to avoid `volumes_from:` in favor of being explicit about what volumes are actually getting mounted.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: my-application:latest
    volumes:
      - /config/$ENV:/config
```